# How to extract only audio from downloading video? Python yt-dlp

Tags: python, video, youtube, yt-dlp

I need to download only audio from youtube video. For this I use the yt-dlp tool.

In the console, I enter the following command, which downloads the audio as a .webm. I change the extension to .mp3 and everything works fine, it's a regular .mp3 file.

Command: `yt-dlp --extract-audio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJuO985zF8E`

In the python script I'm using this code:

```
import yt_dlp
import os

def download_audio(link):
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL({'extract_audio': True}) as video:
        info_dict = video.extract_info(link, download = True)
        video_title = info_dict['title']
        print(video_title)
        #video.download(link)

download_audio('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJuO985zF8E')
```

But the script does not load the video as an audio file, but as a video. How to solve this problem?

(sorry for my English)

I tried many methods but nothing worked.

Comment: If you don't mind the name of the file, you can use `'outtmpl': 'mySongSample.mp3'` in the options - as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41240945/12511801)

Comment: Just curious, let's say we are only concerned about bandwidth, Will saving only the audio save any bandwidth, or must we download the whole video first anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified and tested your code in Google Collab and it sets the name of the file with the .mp3 extension.

Sources:

- [How to rename downloaded audio files extensions to mp3 with python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72009150/12511801)
- [Change the output name when download with youtube-dl using python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41240945/12511801)

Modified code:

```
def download_audio(link):
  with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL({'extract_audio': True, 'format': 'bestaudio', 'outtmpl': '%(title)s.mp3'}) as video:
    info_dict = video.extract_info(link, download = True)
    video_title = info_dict['title']
    print(video_title)
    video.download(link)    
    print("Successfully Downloaded - see local folder on Google Colab")

download_audio('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJuO985zF8E')
```

Result: a .mp3 file with the name of the YouTube video.

```
KORDHELL - MEMPHIS DOOM.mp3
```

Comment: How can I modify audio quality in this function?